# Hot Reload no longer detects code changes

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, hot-reload

I am hoping someone came across this before.  I am using VS 2022 (17.3.3), and debugging a Blazor web server project.  It has been working fine for a long time, but I recently changed a few options, and now it won't detect code changes when I make them while running.

When I do, it simply says at the bottom left corner "No code changes detected."

The changes I made were:

1. Tools / Options / Debugging, General - turn off "Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging"
2. In Project file, added the following to speed up Intellisense in Blazor component pages:

```
    <Target Name="DisableAnalyzers" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile" Condition="'$(DesignTimeBuild)' == 'true'">
        <ItemGroup>
            <Analyzer Remove="@(Analyzer)" Condition="'%(Filename)' == 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators'" />
            <Analyzer Remove="@(Analyzer)" Condition="'%(Filename)' == 'System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration'" />
            <Analyzer Remove="@(Analyzer)" Condition="'%(Filename)' == 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Generators'" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
```

Comment: In your `.csproj` file, do you happen to have the line `<UseRazorSourceGenerator>false</UseRazorSourceGenerator>`?

Comment: Nope, it’s not in there anywhere.

Comment: Well, I had a similar problem recently, and the line of code I mentioned in my first comment was set to false in my project file. When I changed that to true, Hot Reload started working again. I suspect this line: `<Analyzer Remove="@(Analyzer)" Condition="'%(Filename)' == 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators'" />` that you added is the culprit. I'm no expert, but I think that is worth checking.